# Why is UIPickerView hiding embedded UIImageView's within its selector?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, nslayoutconstraint

**Scenario:** 
Display a UIImageView subview.  Superview is Red.

**Problem:** UIImageView disappears within selector.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
                viewForRow row: Int,
                forComponent component: Int,
                reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    let isMainPicker = (numberOfPickerComponents == 1)
    let isStartNode = (component == 0)

    var myView:UIView?

    if (isMainPicker) {
       ...
    } else {
        myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 42, height: 42))
        let imageView = pickerNodeData[row]
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView!.addSubview(imageView)

        let constraint1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0.5-[iv(42)]", metrics: nil, views: ["iv":imageView])
        let constraint2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[iv(42)]", metrics: nil, views: ["iv":imageView])

        myView!.addConstraints(constraint1)
        myView!.addConstraints(constraint2)

        myView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    return myView!
}
```

Here's the initial screen:

[image]

Here's after a rotation. 
Notice some UIImageViews [circle (character)] disappear:

[image]

Why is this happening?  
How do I make each row contain its UIImageView?